# Django: Can't get current logged in user in DRF RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to return the reports written by the currently logged in author. I have defined a custom user model through `AbstractBaseUser`. I want to use `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` so that the author can retrieve as well as edit and delete reports.

I defined these models: `CustomUser`, used as default user model and for authentication. `ReporterProfile`, users need to fill this model when they promote themselves as authors. . The `Report` model stores all submitted reports. The `reporterprofile` field in `Report` model has a `ForeignKey` relationship with the `ReporterProfile` model, which in turn, has a `ForeignKey` relation with `CustomUser` model.

My model definitions:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


class ReporterProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dob = models.DateField(auto_now=False, blank=True, help_text="YYYY-MM-DD")
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=22, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

This is my view:

```
class MyReportsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer(request.user)
    queryset = Report.objects.all()  # need to get the currently logged in user
```

With this, I am getting the error: `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`.

This is my serializer:

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ('reporterprofile', 'slug', 'title', 'column', 'summary', 'body', 'created', 'modified', 'published',)
```

How do I fetch the reports submitted by the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the **`get_queryset()`** method

```
class MyReportsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Report.objects.filter(reporterprofile__user=self.request.user)
```

You can access the ***current logged-in user*** by calling **`self.request.user`** in anywhere in the view class.

Note: The expression ***`filter(user=self.request.user)`*** probably make some field error since there is no direct relation with **Auth user model** in **`Report`**

Comment: Yes I got this error: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: body, column, column_id, comments, created, draft, id, modified, published, reporterprofile, reporterprofile_id, reportimage, slug, summary, title`

Comment: add your related\ models

Comment: Just added the two models.

Comment: It worked. But I had to resort to using `ListAPIView`. Which I understand that I can't update or delete from a bulk result using `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`.